# Change file name in JarOutputStream

Tags: java, file, rename

So I have been working with a Derby DB and can write to and work with the data.  I'm now trying to pack it into a single archive file(jar).  I can get it to pack and unpack with no issues.  Well except one.
I can get it to pack into a jar but it has an extra folder depth.  So if I pack up the directory that is named "December", and inside that archive I also get a "December" folder with the contents inside it.  Is there a way I can remove that extra folder either in packing or unpacking?

I have tried to play with the file's name but if I mess with it I get errors saying it can't find the file after I renamed it. I tried this both before it's packed and while unpacking it.  Closes I got was each file name in the main directory but all the files are 0kb.  I even try to change the pack directory to "December*", but it didn't like that.

```
public class JarPack {
public static void pack(String name,String dir) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    System.out.println(dir);
    Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
    manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0");
    JarOutputStream target = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(name), manifest);
    add(new File(dir), target);
    target.close();
}

private static void add(File source, JarOutputStream target) throws IOException{
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    try
    {
        if (source.isDirectory())
        {
            String name = source.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
            if (!name.isEmpty())
            {
                if (!name.endsWith("/"))
                    name += "/";
                JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
                entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
                target.putNextEntry(entry);
                target.closeEntry();
            }
            for (File nestedFile: source.listFiles())
                add(nestedFile, target);
            return;
        }

        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(source.getPath().replace("\\", "/"));
        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
        target.putNextEntry(entry);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            int count = in.read(buffer);
            if (count == -1)
                break;
            target.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        target.closeEntry();
    }
    finally{
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void unPack(String name,String dir) throws java.io.IOException {
    java.util.jar.JarFile jarfile = new java.util.jar.JarFile(new java.io.File(name));
    java.util.Enumeration<java.util.jar.JarEntry> enu= jarfile.entries();
    while(enu.hasMoreElements()){
        String destdir = dir;
        java.util.jar.JarEntry je = enu.nextElement();

        if (!je.getName().equals("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")){
            java.io.File fl = new java.io.File(destdir, je.getName());
            if(!fl.exists()){
                fl.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                fl = new java.io.File(destdir, je.getName());
            }
            if(je.isDirectory()){
                continue;
            }
            java.io.InputStream is = jarfile.getInputStream(je);
            java.io.FileOutputStream fo = new java.io.FileOutputStream(fl);
            while(is.available()>0){
                fo.write(is.read());
            }
            fo.close();
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It seems to me that this code is working as designed. It's rather arbitrary to suppress a second directory level just because its name is the same as its parent. The second `fl = new java.io.File(destdir, je.getName());` is unnecessary. Your unpack copy loop is not correct: it is never correct to use `available()` as a test for end of stream. Use the same loop you used when packing. It will be much quicker, too. Your logic around `fl.exists()` and `je.isDirectory()` isn't correct. If `je` is a directory you should call `fl.mkdirs()`, and you shouldn't worry about `fl.exists()` at all.

Comment: A lot of this code is from this site to get it working, I will look at those extra loops.  And yes the it works as intended but trying to get not to add the second level.  I know it grabbing that folder and compressing it but I want it to grab the contents and not the folder it's self.